# How to install a package in perl using PPM

Tags: perl

I am having a query regarding there is no perl package in PPM for Excel .I have found one package online not able install that . Can any one guide me in installing the same.

I am using the windows machine. Active perl version is 5.20 .

Comment: Which module do you like to install?

Comment: Excel::Writer::XLSX

Comment: Have you tried `ppm install Excel-Writer-XLSX`

Answer (score 0):

> Module availability is dependent on ActivePerl version and your
>   operating system. The PPM client will show exactly what is available
>   on your current version and operating system. - [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/ppm-perl-modules)

Alternatively you can use `cpan`.

Use cpan command as `cpan Modulename`

```
$ cpan HTML::Parser
```

To install dependencies automatically follow the below

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan[1]>  o conf prerequisites_policy follow
cpan[2]>  o conf commit
exit
```

I prefer [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus), it installs dependencies automatically. Just do

```
$ cpanm HTML::Parser
```

Comment: `cpan` also installs dependencies by default, and generally gives much more useful error messages if something goes wrong.

Comment: @Borodin: You mean to say `prerequisites_policy` is set to `follow` by default?

Comment: I don't know about that specific option, but I've never had to change anything to get `cpan` to install dependencies.